# How to tell someone to Reply All in an email

Tags: email, email-etiquette

My boss recently asked me to cc them and my other colleague in all emails that I send to our patrons. I've been  receiving responses that are send to me only. Is it okay if next time i add "please Reply All to this email" at the end of that email?

Comment: Consider putting "Please reply all" at the *beginning* so people don't miss it.

Answer (score 15):

The first time they forget to do this, simply send a reply (not a forward!) adding back the missing contacts. You should then simply include the text:

> "Re-adding Tom, Dick and Harry to the email chain".

After this happens a few times, they will get the idea. Doesn't meant they won't make mistakes in the future.

Comment: Maybe put a hyphen between "re" and "adding", to avoid the similarity with "Reading" (the hyphen is particularly important if you say "sent" rather than "add").

Comment: almost this but if you have authority over those, you can be more direct saying that. 
"Thanks @John. Please reply all so that everyone is on same page. I am adding others back".  And then continue your response.

Comment: @PagMax These are patrons, so if anything the authority flows the other way. But point taken.

Comment: Sorry I missed that @GregoryCurrie. Yes then I think your original suggestion is best.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think that is appropriate.

However, if they forget to reply all, can you forward their messages to all ?

Comment: I think it will look slightly different to the end receiver.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely fine and I have done it many times. Simply state up from to please reply to all in the current distribution.

If someone doesn't honor the request, reply and state that you are adding so and so back to the thread.

Answer (score -7):

It looks to me like a technical issue only.

If you have IT department, ask them to update his default to 'Reply All'
in case of no IT department, ask him to do it himself

Most messaging / email clients have the option for default reply configuration

Comment: This is a terrible strategy to use reply-all as a default behavior in an email client.  You can almost guarantee that someone will receive an email that they shouldn't have, and the sender will be in the middle of some mess!

Comment: This would be a very bad idea. Overuse of Reply All is far more prevalent than underuse of it.